Does "a mental condition" mean "a mental state" or "a mental problem"? If it means both, are both senses common?
My assumption is that both senses are common and what a mental condition means depends on the context. For example:


My mental condition isn't good these days. I'm under a lot of stress. (mental state)
I have a mental condition that makes me get angry easily. (mental problem)


I think the question can also be put this way: Can we say "I'm in a good mental condition" to mean that we are mentally well?

For No. 1 I normally hear "mental health" which could be anything between schizophrenia  and sadness. 2. sounds OK to me. In a job interview or in a CV I would avoid mentioning my mental health altogether unless it would explain my eccentricities or mood swings which were impossible to mask.

According to a 1984 lecture I heard by Professor John Searle, 'mental states' are biological and therefore something that computers can't have, and this is why they will never be truly 'conscious'.

It is interesting that less careful speakers in the UK will say 'I've got mental health' when what they mean is the exact opposite.

@MichaelHarvey  Lots of words/phrases get overly abbreviated that way - the most obvious recent one would be that these days "Ethnic" tends to mean "Ethnic minority "

Thanks, everybody. @Mari-LouA It's strange that I've heard of "physical condition" a lot, but somehow "mental condition" is uncommon.

I don't believe I've ever heard "my mental condition" used to refer to current state.  But "my mental state" is common.

I. Mental Condition:.
First part of OP's query:

My assumption is that both senses are common and what a mental condition means depends on the context. For example:
My mental condition isn't good these days. I'm under a lot of stress. (mental state).
I have a mental condition that makes me get angry easily. (mental problem)

You can refer to both mental health and mental illness under the more general and inclusive term "mental condition.
This term encompasses all mental states, both good and bad, that are associated with an individual's mental health.
Mental conditions can vary from typical mood swings and mental states to diagnosed mental illnesses.
II. Difference between mental health and mental illness.
As seen above, mental condition means both.

The terms “mental health” and “mental illness” are sometimes interchanged, but they differ in meaning. While mental health refers to anyone’s state of mental, emotional well-being, mental illnesses are diagnosed conditions that affect thoughts and behaviors. Though anyone can have moments of poor mental health, not everyone has a mental illness. On the other hand, someone with a mental illness can achieve sound mental health.
https://taylorcounselinggroup.com/blog/mental-health-vs-mental-illness/#:~:text=While%20mental%20health%20refers%20to,everyone%20has%20a%20mental%20illness.

III. Usages of the term - "mental condition..
Ref ludwig.com.

It is often used to refer to a person's mental state or psychological well-being, or to describe a specific mental illness or disorder. Example:
"The doctor diagnosed him with bipolar disorder, a mental condition that can cause extreme mood swings..
.
The New York Times.
1.In June, Mr. Kaine issued a six-month delay of Mr. Walton's execution to allow for an independent evaluation of his mental condition and competence.
2.The miners are being divided into three teams, Mr. Golborne said, depending on their physical and mental condition, and on their "skills".
("Mental condition" in the first news item means "mental illness" and in the second it means "mental state")


IV. Can we say "I'm in a good mental condition" to mean that we are mentally well?

Given the dual connotations of "mental condition"—both positive and negative—you should refrain from using this expression. Saying something in this manner in front of an interviewer runs the risk of being misinterpreted.
